# OneHotEncoder stops returning transformed array after a specific number of features (category columns) added

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

The following code is meant to OneHotEncode the specified columns (features). I have 54 features, and I want to encode them all, but for some reason the max number of features I can encode is 25, if I increase the number of features to encode beyond that, .fit_transorm() will return nothing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer


# ======================== 1 - Importing the data ========================
# - Dataset has 54 features and 1 label (55 columns)
# - 10k examples

datasetPath = "10k-States(0).csv"

dataset = pd.read_csv(datasetPath)

x_train = dataset.iloc[:, 0:54]
y_train = dataset.iloc[:, 54]

# ===================== 2 - Encode x (input) values ======================

# Columns to be encoded (should be 54, but 25 is max that works...)
cols_to_encode = list(range(25))

# 'categories' parameter is multiplied by same number as above, 
# every feature has the same classes (labels)
transformer = ColumnTransformer( 
    [('one_hot_encoder', OneHotEncoder(categories=[[0,1,2,3,4,5]]*25), cols_to_encode)],  
    remainder='passthrough'                                              
)

x = transformer.fit_transform(x_train)
```

This is the output when I have <=25 columns:
[image: Dataset variables]

These are all fine, but as soon as I increase to 26 columns, or more, the value of x is (), nothing. I have no idea what is going on...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
columnnumberist = [] #insert here all the columns numbers
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
one = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = columnnumberlist) #Might get a deprecation warning
X  = one.fit_transform(X)
X=X.toarray()
```